# JWT Token Authentication can not access other request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, jwt

I'm new to JWT Authentication, just have done a tutorial about JWT. I successfully generated JWT token when register and authenticate. But when I use it for other request access I got 403 error. I really dont know what cause of the problem. Here is the code:

JWTService.java

```java
public class JwtService {
    
    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "This is my secret key";

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }
    
    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    
    // create token depends on user credentials
    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }
    
    public String generateToken(Map<String, Object> extraClaims, UserDetails userDetails) {
        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                //check if the token is valid or not
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                //set how long this token is active
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 24))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(),SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }
    
    
    // method to validate token
    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && isTokenExpired(token);
    }
    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {

        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims :: getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts
                .parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    //
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
//          .antMatchers("/v1/api/**")
            .antMatchers("/v1/api/auth/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter.java

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull     FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String username;
        if(authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        
        //check if the user is authorized or not
        if(username !=null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            // check if token is valid or not
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        username, null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // update authentication token
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/api/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private final IUserService iUserService;
    @Autowired
    private final IRoleService iRoleService;

    private final JwtService jwtService;

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt;
    

    @PostMapping(value = "/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(@RequestBody LoginDTO dto) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(dto.getUsername(), dto.getPassword()));
        User user = iUserService.findByUsername(dto.getUsername());
        String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(jwtToken);

    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody RegisterDTO dto) {
        User user = dto.convertToEntity();
        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add(iRoleService.findRoleByName("ROLE_CUSTOMER"));
        user.setRoles(roles);
        user.setPassword(bcrypt.encode(user.getPassword()));
        iUserService.registerUser(user);
        String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(jwtToken);
    }

}
```

I have searched for solutions for hours but cannot find the answer

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have an error in your **isTokenValid** method:

```
public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String username = extractUsername(token);
    return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && isTokenExpired(token);
}
```

In my opinion it should be

```
public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String username = extractUsername(token);
    return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
}
```

I created a simple app using your classes and after this fix it works properly

Comment: Its fixed. Thank you so much, you are such a lifesaver <3